# Change mouse cursor shape for the whole window (inside & outside the app window)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to change the cursor shape using pyqt5, for the whole window, Is that possible?
In pyqt5, I can use

```py
self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
```

I also tried

```py
QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
```

But this just change the cursor only while mouse is over the app. I want to change for the whole PC display, even when the mouse is outside the app window.

Comment: With Qt, you can't. You have to find the way to change the cursor for the specific system you are on.

Comment: Qt only changes the cursor while it is inside the application so if you want to make that change on the entire screen then you must use system libraries

Comment: @eyllanesc Can you point to some library!